# cabal-install and ghc 7.10.1

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I just upgraded to ghc 7.10.1 and whenever I try use cabal-install I run into the following error:

> ghc: ghc no longer supports single-file style package databases (dist/package.conf.inplace) use 'ghc-pkg init' to create the database with the correct format.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think that means that your version of cabal is too old for GHC 7.10.

Comment: Try to `cabal install cabal-install` and then make sure new version is on the path. You can check version of `cabal` this way: `cabal --version`.

Comment: Don't forget to refresh package list `cabal update`.

Comment: I thought this was the error as well but I cant update my cabal because when I run `cabal install cabal-install` I get the same error as above

Comment: Try to move/delete ~/.cabal and ~/.ghc, then run again `cabal install cabal-install`

Comment: Tried that same error. Here is the full error report: http://pastebin.com/8kwRgy6s

Comment: What's your cabal version? `cabal --version`

Comment: As @MichaelSnoyman said, apparently your cabal version is too old to even build the new cabal-install. Upgrade it to >= 1.22

Comment: when i try to install >= 1.22 it runs into an error where my ghc base is too advanced. http://pastebin.com/wVi50tMk

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac OS X and are using homebrew it may be that you installed Cabal through `haskell-platform` package, which is outdated with no direct upgrade path.

You should uninstall `haskell-platform` and reinstall Cabal using the `cabal-install` package.

Answer (score 0):

It could well be you have a newer cabal on your path but can't find it because the old one shadows it. So looking for `where cabal` may help you resolve that. Barring that, you can download a newer cabal binary from the [cabal homepage](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html).